Convert Tkinter GUI app in Python into a standalone .exe along with sqlite db
i am building a Tkinter GUI app using python, and my use case is like below:
I am creating a .exe file using pyinstaller, and i want to include an sqlite db with it.
Eventhough i included it while building the app, it is creating the db again instead of using the included db. What i actually want to do is,i will use it multiple systems, user will enter a secret key, in the first time he uses. the .exe file should save the key and use it for running the program(it should not store via an external source/file).
I used this command to build the app:
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "backend_processes.py;." --add-data "user_data.db;." --hidden-import=pydicom.encoders.gdcm --hidden-import=pydicom.encoders.pylibjpeg main.py
does anyone know, how can i solve this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Even you can use the embedded db file, but the changes created during execution will not be kept because the embedded db will be extracted again and used everytime the executabe is executed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78290574/20782948 i hope it helps. this works for me though
